# Strage effect in silverlight with checkbox and Flow direction

Tags: silverlight, xaml

If I Define `<Checkbox Content="Text" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">`
Text appers on Left side of checkbox

But if if define `<Checkbox Content="Text:" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">` Note the : symbol
then i see strange effect its not Text: CheckBox but its diplsys :Text Chekbox the : Symbol appers one Left side of text and it is for all that kind of charectes also for ?

Any ideas??

Comment: This is a very nice little trick for putting the text on the left hand side of the checkbox without retemplating the control.  Useful for test apps and demos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, as RTL languages expect to have the colon to the left of the text. See this [excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=558i6t1dKEAC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=FlowDirection+RightToLeft+and+colon&source=bl&ots=g_ocEICQNM&sig=Ms1M7d33ozGOSUugszSGUKyXshc&hl=en&ei=fb-ATZ-mCqy60QGZ8v3wCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=FlowDirection%20RightToLeft%20and%20colon&f=false) from the Programming Wpf book.