# Silverlight RTL Support

Tags: silverlight, localization, right-to-left

I know Silverlight 4 added support for RTL languages through the FlowDirection property.

Being new to RTL I just want to make sure I understand what should happen when I set the FlowDirection property.  I noticed that the text alignment for the TextBoxes are now right aligned and the whole UI basically mirrors itself by switching everything that was on the left over to the right.  So this all seems to be working fine.  However, when entering text in a Textbox, surely the text should complete from right to left now as well.  So I if enter the word 'run' in a TextBox with FlowDirection set to RTL, then surely it should read 'nur' and not 'run'?  Is my understanding correct, but currently the TextBox still displays it as 'run' even thought it is right-aligned in the control itself.

Comment: You can try WPF or WindowsForms to test how exactly it should work in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTL-ness of the text will be automatically by the unicode text itself. So if you chuck in some Arabic text into the TextBox, it'll be in the correct direction (RTL), regardless of whether the FlowDirection is set or not. The FlowDirection is just for mirroring the UI, it's not about changing the text. Apparently there's also some clever [special treatment of colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325317/strage-effect-in-silverlight-with-checkbox-and-flow-direction).

So basically: yup, that's correct, working as intended.

Comment: Thanks - that clarifies it nicely.