# PowerView filter with Arabic - Silverlight with Arabic

Tags: silverlight, arabic, right-to-left, powerview

When I type text in PowerView filter, the Arabic orientation goes wrong.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot]

On the left of the screenshot it shows the filter before typing in the text field, on the right it shows the filter after typing in the text field.

The Arabic gets changes/corrupted I believe because of the yellow highlight.
My silver light version is (5.1.30214.0)

I have tried this [workaround](http://tech.ahmedshokr.com/2012/05/01/solve-silverlight-arabic-text-issue-in-sharepoint-2010-organization-browser-and-media-web-parts/), but it did not solve the issue.

Any help please?

Comment: we need some code here to see. I think it's a "FlowDirection" like [this issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325317/strage-effect-in-silverlight-with-checkbox-and-flow-direction

Comment: @MESEE, Unfortunately there is no code, this is PowerView, it is built-in, you can't access the code.