# TextBox inside DockPanel - strange behavior with special characters

Tags: wpf, textbox, dockpanel

I have a `TextBox` inside a `DockPanel` whose `FlowDirection` is `RightToLeft`.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
   <TextBox Text="Hello@"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Inside the TextBox, it displays like this:

> @Hello

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: As a workaround you can create a style that is LeftToRight, and apply it for a single TextBlock that contains '@'. I'd love to learn how to have it working without a workaround though.

Comment: It's by design, people have issues with colon symbol in RightToLeft too. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326274/275330